# asp net app 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. from a remote client. Windows Server 2008

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, permissions, windows-server-2008

I have just deployed a Asp.Net MVC 4 application to a brand new web server here in my company. It is running Windows Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 and IIS7.5

- I configured the application in IIS
- Enabled Anonymous Authentication and Forms Authentication and
  pointed to the right path
- I´ve added NERTWORK SERVICES to the app folder and also in .NET
  Authorization All Users is set as allow.

Trying to access the application from a remote client computer I am getting

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
```

I am able to access IIS page.
Is there somenthing else with the permissions I should have a look at?
Thanks

Comment: What application pool is the app using? Its own or an existing one? And can you access the site locally from the remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When users access the login page, it has not been authenticated yet. The anonymous user for my application pool is IUSR.

I needed to add IUSR with Read and Execute privilege on the application folder to solve my problem.